# Adding data from a column to another table's column Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, relational-database

So, I want to store some products to the `product` table. I managed that. But now I want to attach a `user id` to each product, so it can correspond to a different user.

As for now, I have tried this, but it doesn't seem to work:

```
public function store(){
    $product = Request::all();
    $product = Product::create($product);
    $user = User::whereId(Request::input('user'))->first();
    $product->users()->attach($user);
    return redirect()->route('products');
}
```

The relationship between `users` and `products` is this: a `user_id` column in `products` table is `foreign key`and references to the `id` on `users` table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use relation methods to save related objects as:

*Assuming relation name in `User` model is `products`*

```
public function store() {
  $product_array = Request::all();

  $product = Auth::user()->products()->create($product_array);

  return redirect()->route('products');
}
```

Here the `create` method will automatically add the appropriate `user_id` value to the new `Product` model.

Comment: This returns me an error in $product = $user->products()->create($product); 
Call to a member function products() on null.


I modified it like this: $product = Auth::user()->products()->create($product); 
and now it is working